# XAML, giving full width and height to my text

Tags: xaml

I have a grid with 3 rows, in my top row (200px height) i want a text on a blue background. How do i specify that my textblock should fill the space? when i add it it only fits the space the text occupy. Tried with a ViewBox, but that resized the text also, i want that to be a fixed size...

anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is an example of size autofill for 3 different controls in given grid in XAML. Autofill is default, so you don't need to set anything additional, just make sure margin is not set. I tested this solution in MS Expression Blend and it works OK.

```
    <Grid Height="400" Width="250" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button"/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Test Text block" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these four properties from the xaml if they are set when `TextBlock` is defined, or set them to the default values:

1. `HorizontalAlignment` (Defaults to `Stretch`)
2. `VerticalAlignment` (Defaults to `Stretch`)
3. `Width` (Default to `Auto`)
4. `Height` (Default to `Auto`)

Your `TextBlock` should now auto stretch and fit the row.

Also make sure that your `Grid` is also wide enough or is set to fit your `Window`. Your `Grid`'s width might also be the culprit.